# How to calculate the min-max amount of A, B, C to maximize Y?

Tags: statistics

I have the following table where I have the variables $A$, $B$, $C$ that generate the output $Y$.

[image]

What kind of algorithm can I use to know the min-max amount of $A$, $B$, $C$ that maximizes the $Y$ value?

Comment: So, $Y = f (A,B,C)$. What do you know about $f$?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: Is a personal problem ✌️  the relationship between this features is that I send A, B, C to a system and it returns Y, I want to maximize Y.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?  Are all possible inputs listed on the table? Or are you providing just a few inputs to "learn" what $f$ is?

Comment: Are all possible inputs listed on the table?
Yes, there are no more inputs

Comment: In that case, why not find the maximal value of $Y$, which is $19$, and then find its pre-image, which is $f^{-1} (19) = (5,15,2)$?